# My browser-based JS API client works, but seems very slow to process requests. What could the problem be?

Tags: javascript

[image]

You can see that each request is taking less than a second, and when I look at the 'Waterfall' details in Chrome console, nothing shown there is taking more than a fraction of a second, so I can't understand why requests are being processed so slowly? I'm not really sure how to read the overall time elapsed, but if I'm reading the graph at the top right, I think it's taken ~3000 seconds to process 41 requests, so that's around 75 seconds per request!!

Can anyone guide me to see what's actually causing such big delays? TIA.

Edit - this is the code where I set my delay:

```
let lastRequest = 0;
const accessInterval = 1000 // delay between requests in ms

//some code

function delayFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setInterval(() => {
           let current = new Date().getTime();
           if (lastRequest < (current - accessInterval)) {
                lastRequest = current;
                resolve();
            }
        },10)
    })
}
```

Edit2: more info. - the API I'm accessing is https://api.discogs.com/.

Looking at https://www.discogs.com/developers/ I see it says "Requests are throttled by the server by source IP to 60 per minute for authenticated requests, and 25 per minute for unauthenticated requests, with some exceptions.".

The response headers show:

```
X-Discogs-Media-Type: discogs.v2
X-Discogs-Ratelimit: 25
X-Discogs-Ratelimit-Remaining: 25
```

...so I guess my app must be unauthenticated, right? I'm going to try increasing the delay between requests accordingly.

Edit3: I just noticed something else...

Under 'request headers' is shown...

```
Provisional headers are shown
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36              (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

...which is bad according to https://www.discogs.com/developers/

I think I will try a test with Firefox and see if it appears to use my custom `user-agent` in the header.

Edit: the code that actually does the API call is:

```
function getRelease(id) {
  return delayFunction()
    .then(() => fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSVforDiscogs/0.1',
      }
    }))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseReleaseData)
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Are you sending those requests all at once ? if so, then you're limited by the browser max connections

Comment: @Manish Khedekar - OK, I've added what seems to be the relevant code.

Comment: @darklightcode - no, they are sent sequentially AFAIK, and there is supposed to be a 1000ms delay between each.

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but if you just need to do something every ~1s why are you going to all this trouble?

Comment: @Dave Newton - I'm really not sure what you mean? All what trouble? What difference does the 1s delay make?

Comment: @double-happiness Making 100 calls to only approximate 1s anyway is pointless. It's not clear that you need to do this via promises, either, but no clue what context your code is running in.

Comment: @Dave Newton

I'm really not sure why it's 'pointless'.

My code takes values known as release IDs from a .csv file, it then looks them up  in a site API, and returns all the data. So for instance looking up release ID 249504 will return all the data in https://api.discogs.com/releases/249504.

I'll add the code that actually does the API call to the OP.

Comment: You never clear your intervals so after 41 requests you have 41 intervals all trying to run every 10ms

Comment: You should do `const interval = setInterval(...`, and then clear it right before resolving the Promise with: `clearInterval( interval );`

Comment: Your delayFunction doesn't really work though, since you could call getRelease 100 times and then all the delayFunction Promises could resolve at approximately the same time as each other, before any fetch requests are sent

Comment: @Paulpro

Thanks, but I'm not sure how to fit that into the rest of the code? can you show me how that fits with the following?

    `function delayFunction() {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setInterval(() => {
          let current = new Date().getTime();
          if (lastRequest < (current - accessInterval)) {
            lastRequest = current;
            resolve();
          }
        },10)
      })
    }`

Comment: Bottom line is that there are libraries that already exist that handle throttling: you'd line up your requests and they get made at the (a) rate you set and (b) not too many at once since there are hard browser limits, although I assume browsers already handle this. I'd probably (a) take a step back and see if you can find a library that suits your needs, and/or (b) rethink how you're doing this at all.

Comment: Well, the best solution is probably to just get rid of `delayFunction` completely and let the caller of getRelease handle the concurrency control, not calling getRelease more than once per second.

Comment: With async/await you could just do something like `let lastRequest = new Date - 1000; for ( const id of releaseIds ) { await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, new Date() - lastRequest ) ); const release = await getRelease( id ); }`

Comment: It is working much faster now, but it still hits a 429 error after 10 requests. I'll try to look into these libraries Dave mentioned, but I'm really not sure where to start.

Comment: @Paulpro - thanks, but I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @double-happiness You would need to put all of that in an async function. It could be an anonymous one but you need to handle errors. `(async function ( ) { // the code from previous comment })().catch( err => { // Handle error here} );` or if you want to handle errors (which you probably should, because the above will stop all subsequent requests if a single one errors) for individual requests (maybe you want to retry them a few times) put `const release = await getRelease( id );` in a `try { } ` block and handle it in the catch

Comment: @Paulpro - thanks. Any chance of putting all of your suggestions together in a top-level response? I'm finding it a bit tricky to follow all of this in the comments. TY

Comment: @double-happiness I'm on mobile which makes it a bit difficult. I will be able to in a little while

Comment: @Paulpro That would be great if you could at some point. Thanks a lot for the help so far.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your approach.

Problem 1:

Every time you call `delayFunction` you start another interval, which means that if you call `getRelease` many times you will have many intervals polling at once, when you really only need at most one interval or timer to achieve your goal.

Problem 2:

`getRelease` calls `fetch` ***asynchronously*** after the delayFunction Promise resolves:

```
delayFunction()
  .then(() => fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`
```

That means that you could have several calls to delayFunction all resolve before any calls to fetch are made; completely defeating the purpose of delayFunction.

Problem 3:

You never clear your interval after creating it, so even after the Promise resolves your interval is still polling. That means that every time you call delayFunction you create one more interval that runs every 10ms. If you call `getRelease` 1000 times you create 1000 intervals and none of them are ever stopped.

**The solution**

First of all, you should move the concurrency control outside of `getRelease`. It is more useful for `getRelease` to have a single purpose and give control over how often it is called to the caller. So to start, remove your delayFunction and change getRelease so it looks like this:

```
function getRelease(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSVforDiscogs/0.1',
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(parseReleaseData)
}
```

Then make the caller handle the throttling of calls to `getRelease`. You can find many libraries or snippets for this. Keywords to search for are `asynchronous` and `throttle`. With async/await you can do it pretty easily. You can do it without async/await too, of course, but it is not as clean of code, so you might just want to use a library for it if you don't want to use async/await.

Here is an example using async/await (assuming your ids are in an array called `releaseIds`):

```
;(async function ( ) { 

  const accessInterval = 1000;
  let lastRequest = new Date - accessInterval;

  for ( const id of releaseIds ) {

    // Wait until one has passed since the previous request was initiated
    await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, lastRequest + accessInterval - new Date() ) );

    try { 
      lastRequest = new Date;
      const release = await getRelease( id );
    } catch ( err ) {
      // Handle request failure here, 
      //   Depending on the error, perhaps add another delay and retry 
      //     or loop up to some limit retrying on each iteration, increasing the delay each time you get a 429 error
      //   At a minimum just log the skipped release id with console.log( id );
    }
  }

} )();
```

This is meant to be an example rather than the exact code that you should use. There are many options you might want to adjust. Perhaps you want a minimum delay between requests instead of (or in addition to) a delay between the start of requests, or maybe you want to allow up to 5 calls at a time instead of doing them one at a time  (you would likely see a significant performance increase by doing that). You can find many other examples by searching with the keywords I mentioned, just remember to keep the concurrency control outside of `getRelease`.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful reply. Unfortunately I'm having quite a few problems though. For the first `getRelease` function you wrote I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. When I comment your version of `getRelease`out and reinstate the old version I get other errors, but perhaps I had just better fix one thing at a time.

Comment: OK, I think I've possibly fixed the problem in `getRelease`, by deleting the last `)`. As for `async function`, I'm not sure what to enter in `const id of releaseIds`, because I'm honestly not sure what the array of IDs is really called. I tried `idsClean`, which is one of the possibilities, but I'm getting `csv.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: idsClean is not defined`. That's a bit odd to me, because `for (const id of idsClean)` is also in line 40, but that doesn't seem to cause an error. I also tried another possibility, `id`, but get `Cannot access 'id' before initialization`.

Comment: Yeah, I had an extra `)` in getRelease. It is fixed now.

Comment: @double-happiness How were you calling `getRelease` before?

Comment: `function getRelease(id) {
    return delayFunction()
    .then(() => fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
      {
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'CSVforDiscogs/0.1',
        }
      }))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(parseReleaseData)
    }`

Comment: @double-happiness I'm wondering how you were calling it, not how it looked itself. I.E. where do you get the ids from the csv?

Comment: TBH I'm really not sure. `  function parseReleaseData(data) {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.')
    return `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist`

    const id = data.id` maybe?